# I want to designate a type according to the conditions of the object property

Tags: typescript, types, conditional-types, typescript-types

There is organizational data with a hierarchical structure.

Organizational nodes are divided into Root, Dept, and User.

The object property type is assigned a type suitable for node data.

So, I hope that the node interface suitable for the object type will be attached conditionally.

To solve this problem, I tried Index Types and Conditional Types, but they were not successful.

Any help would be appreciated‍♂️

```
export enum NodeType {
  root = "root",
  dept = "dept",
  user = "user",
}

interface Node {
  readonly nodeId: string;
  readonly type: NodeType;
  title: string;
  childNodes?: Node[];
}

interface RootNode extends Node {
  type: NodeType.root;
  childNodes?: (DeptNode | UserNode)[];
}

interface DeptNode extends Node {
  type: NodeType.dept;
  childNodes?: (DeptNode | UserNode)[];

  deptId: string;
  companyCode: string;
}

interface UserNode extends Node {
  type: NodeType.user;
  childNodes?: UserNode[];

  employeeNumber: string;
  userPrincipalName: string;
}

/**
 * from hierarchy data to flatting data
 */
function flatting(st: Node) {
  flatCompanyData.push(st);
  if (st.childNodes) {
    st.childNodes.forEach((x) => flatting(x));
  }
}

const companyData: RootNode = {
  nodeId: "0",
  type: NodeType.root,
  title: "Company 1",
  childNodes: [
    {
      nodeId: "0.0",
      type: NodeType.dept,
      title: "Department 1",
      deptId: "A1",
      companyCode: "557",
      childNodes: [
        {
          nodeId: "0.0.0",
          type: NodeType.user,
          title: "User 1",
          employeeNumber: "201911",
          userPrincipalName: "user01@test.com",
        },
        {
          nodeId: "0.0.1",
          type: NodeType.user,
          title: "User 2",
          employeeNumber: "201912",
          userPrincipalName: "user02@test.com",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      nodeId: "0.1",
      type: NodeType.dept,
      title: "Department 2",
      deptId: "A2",
      companyCode: "558",
    },
  ],
};
let flatCompanyData: Node[] = [];

flatting(companyData);

// I want to be the type of DeptNode interface because the type of object property is NodeType.dept.
const selectDept = flatCompanyData.filter((x) => x.type === NodeType.dept);
selectDept.forEach((x) => {
  console.log({
    nodeId: x.nodeId,
    type: x.type,
    title: x.title,
    // The type is not affirmed in the node that fits the object property type, so you have to affirm the type yourself.
    deptId: (x as DeptNode).deptId,
    companyCode: (x as DeptNode).companyCode,
  });
});

// I want to be the type of UserNode interface because the type of object property is NodeType.user.
const selectUser = flatCompanyData.filter((x) => x.type === NodeType.user);
selectUser.forEach((x) => {
  console.log({
    nodeId: x.nodeId,
    type: x.type,
    title: x.title,
    // The type is not affirmed in the node that fits the object property type, so you have to affirm the type yourself.
    employeeNumber: (x as UserNode).employeeNumber,
    userPrincipalName: (x as UserNode).userPrincipalName,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two problems in your code:

First of all, an element of type `Node` is not necessarily of type `DeptNode` just because it has `NodeType.dept`. Consider the following object:

```
{
  nodeId: '0',
  type: NodeType.dept,
  title: 'Company 1'
}
```

This is a completely valid `Node` but not a valid `DeptNode` as it lacks the fields `deptId` and `companyCode`. So the compiler is in fact right when it does not treat it as a `DeptNode`. But there is a solution to this. Instead of using an array of `Node`s you can define a union type of all possible node types and use it as type for `flatCompanyData` like this:

```
type NodeUnion = RootNode | DeptNode | UserNode;
let flatCompanyData: NodeUnion[];

// ...

const node = flatCompanyData[0];
if (node.type === NodeType.dept) {
  // x is correctly inferred as DeptNode in here
}
```

With this type the compiler knows, the only way an element in the array could possibly have the type `NodeType.dept` is if it is a `DeptNode` and so the type is inferred correctly.

This still leaves us with the second problem. Even if you use this union type for `flatCompanyData`, your code will still not work. The reason is the `Array.filter` function. For an array of type `T[]` it will always return an array of type `T[]`, no matter what you check inside.

But fortunately typescript comes with a handy solution for this: custom type guards. When defining a function (including an anonymous function) you can use a type predicate as its return type to tell the compiler that this function acts as a type guard.

```
function isDeptNode(node: NodeUnion): node is DeptNode {
  return node.type === NodeType.dept;
}
```

And now you can use this function inside the filter to make typescript realize what you are doing.

```
const selectDept: DeptNode[] = flatCompanyData.filter(isDeptNode);
```

It is also possible to specify a type predicate as the return type of an anonymous function without defining the `isDeptNode` function first.

```
const selectDept: DeptNode[] = flatCompanyData.filter(
  (x): x is DeptNode => x.type === NodeType.dept
);
```